# Retain Sorting After Specific Action - Grails

Tags: grails, gsp

I have a gsp form which displays the list of employees with the details (ie., Employee Name,Designation,Department,Status). All these columns are sortable. After calling a specific action in my controller class (ie., Changing the status of the employee from active to inactive and vice versa) the sorting gets disturbed. I am using the following code to sort while retrieving from DB

```
    String strSort = params.sort ?: "empId";
    strSort += " "
    strSort += params.order?: "asc";
```

Is there any way I can retain the sort order which was there before posting a "Status change" action? If it is how it can be achieved?

Comment: You have to show your actions (controller methods), otherwise it would be difficult to suggest anything.

Comment: How is the status changed ? are you opening up a screen or clicking something that then sends request via jquery (ajax) to controller / controller does something then updates the list - which then turns out to be incorrectly ordered. Or do you physically post the update of status to a controller action that does it then refreshes the page with listing ?

Comment: @vahid I am clicking on status icon which sends request via ajax to controller and sends the emp list back with updated status. But after this action the previous sorting order was distrubed

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways to do it:

- Pass your sort and order parameters to your action and send them back
  with the result.
- Store in session both parameters every time you update them.

To store and retrive from session use something like this:

```
private DEFAULT_SORT = 'myDefaultSort'

def myAction() {
    if (params.sort && params.sort != session.getAttribute('sort-' + actionName)) {
        session.setAttribute('sort-' + actionName, params.sort)
    }
    params.sort = session.getAttribute('sort-' + actionName)?:DEFAULT_SORT
    ...
    //Your existing logic
}
```

If you receive a new/different sort parameter you save it into session. Then you try to load existing parameter from session, if you dont have any value stored, you get a default value.

Comment: Can you please tell me how I can get the sort and order parameters of a current session and pass it to my controller?

Comment: @AnithaKamatchi Look at this answer, is exactly what you need http://stackoverflow.com/a/40151111/3897206

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by rvargas, it is possible through a variety of methods. [queuekit plugin](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-queuekit-plugin) isn't released properly as yet so you could clone grails 3 / grails2 branch depending on which it is you are working with and also clone the test site to go with it to mess with this concept within the plugin:

In short You need to [separate out your search feature](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-queuekit-plugin/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/org/grails/plugin/queuekit/QueueKitController.groovy#L81-L82) and you can do this via a session value or send it as a subset list iteration.

I decided to not use sessions. Then when I click delete The [bean is bound back in with the request sent](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-queuekit-plugin/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/org/grails/plugin/queuekit/QueueKitController.groovy#L123) (which be the id to delete)

At the very end it [relists](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-queuekit-plugin/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/org/grails/plugin/queuekit/QueueKitController.groovy#L138) so no need to do any other here:

The most important bit being when I call the ajax reloadPage or even further postAction used by `delete` function is that I [serialize search form](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-queuekit-plugin/blob/master/grails-app/views/queueKit/main.gsp#L160). The actual search object is kept in a [tidy manner here](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-queuekit-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/org/grails/plugin/queuekit/validation/QueueKitBean.groovy#L95-L109)

But if this is too complex then in the very controller link the session search was commented out. I think you could just enable that forget all this complication and have a searchAgain() feature which renders the _list template like it does if it is `xhr` in my controller and rather than binding bean it binds the `session.search` map instead and if you did go down this route you probably want to change [from g:render to g:include action="searchAgain"](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-queuekit-plugin/blob/master/grails-app/views/queueKit/_list.gsp#L4)

Hope that helps you understand better